# Windows does not recognize HDD after reformatting one partition

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, formatting

I have 2 hard disk drives on my computer :

- On the first one, I have only Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed (dual boot)
- The second HDD has 5 Partitions where I saved documents. Initially, all the 5 partitions where formatted in NTFS.

I have the following Problem : I formatted one partition of the second HDD as ext4, because I wanted to use it for Linux. After a reboot on Windows, all the partitions of the second HDD where not recognized anymore. So I rebooted on Linux and reformatted the one partition from ext4 to NTFS, so that all the partition of the second HDD were formatted as NTFS again. After a new reboot on Windows, nothing changed - the second HDD is not recognized even if all the partition are formatted as NTFS.

Info : By "not regognized", I mean that my Disk Management on Windows looks like this (there should be 5 partition on the disk instead of nothing):

[image]

I wanted to know if there is a tool or a trick that I could use to make Windows recognize my second HDD before I transfer all my data on an external HDD and reformat the second HDD completely.

Answer (score -1):

It's kina weird, for me it was working on Windows 7. (SSD linux/windows - HDD ntfs/ext4). Windows saw only ntfs, ubuntu saw both.

Check it out, maybe your Windows sees your HDD - it can be dismounted.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mount-dismount-drive#1TC=windows-7

Regards